# PHP Issue with Contact Form

Tags: php, html, forms, email, post

Having a problem with a PHP Contact Form.

```
<form action="contactform.php" id="contact-form">
<div id="success"></div>
<ul>
<li class="input-name">
    <input type="text" id="name" class="required" placeholder="Name">
</li> <!-- END input-name -->
<li class="input-email">
    <input type="text" id="email" class="email" placeholder="Email Address">
</li> <!-- END input-name -->
<li class="input-subject">
    <input type="text" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">
</li> <!-- END input-name -->
<li class="input-subject">
    <textarea rows="7" cols="50" id="message" class="required" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
</li> <!-- END input-name -->
</ul> <!-- END #contact -->
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right">Send Message</button>
```

The contents of the PHP is

```
 <?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "joebloggs@email.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Enter your name");
$subject = check_input($_POST['subject'], "Enter a subject");
$email = check_input($_POST['email']);
$message = check_input($_POST['message'], "Write your message");

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}
/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "

Name: $name
E-mail: $email
Subject: $subject

Message:
$message

";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: thanks.html');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please correct the following error:</p>
<strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
<p>Hit the back button and try again</p>

</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

When i try to test the form i am getting a

> Please correct the following error: Enter your name
>   Hit the back button and try again

Even though there is text in the "Name" box on the form.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Couple of things to note (separate from the main issue): Your code is missing an ending `</form>` tag. Secondly, you should use a captcha to avoid spam being submitted through the form.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have any name attributes set in your html:

```
<li class="input-name">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="required" placeholder="Name">
</li> <!-- END input-name -->
<li class="input-email">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="email" placeholder="Email Address">
</li> <!-- Etc Etc -->
```

Answer (score 1):

`method=""` missing in your form and `name=""` attribute missing in all inputs use below form.

```
<form action="contactform.php" method="post" id="contact-form">
<div id="success"></div>
<ul>
<li class="input-name">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="required" placeholder="Name">
</li> <!-- END input-name -->
<li class="input-email">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="email" placeholder="Email Address">
</li> <!-- END input-name -->
<li class="input-subject">
    <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
</li> <!-- END input-name -->
<li class="input-subject">
    <textarea rows="7" cols="50" id="message" name="message" class="required" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
</li> <!-- END input-name -->
</ul> <!-- END #contact -->
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right">Send Message</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. That has helped. The form is now sending problem i am getting now is "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/5/d432350608/htdocs/fleetmotus/beta/mailer.php:7) in /homepages/5/d432350608/htdocs/fleetmotus/beta/mailer.php on line 38" Any idea's?

Comment: there is some data printing before your header make sure there is nothing to display before header.